# Real World Use of the keyword In in .NET Framework

Tags: contravariance

I have accidentally come across the keyword "in". I read an article on MSDN - [in (Generic Modifier) (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx) but still don't quite understand why it is useful. Can someone provide a real world example to show the reason why the keyword "in" is useful?

Thanks.

Comment: check out the multi-part series [Eric Lippert on covariance and contravariance in C#](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6D8YDSvpEYI)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have taken a listen at the series and got some idea why it would be needed and when to use it. Thanks.